# Error al utilizar Application.Evaluation

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy usando esta instrucción para intentar averiguar si una celda tiene formato condicional o no para poder aplicar un formato u otro. Lo hago con este código que pongo a continuación, visto de ejemplo en otras webs, y me da un error de tipo 13 que no coinciden los tipos

```
Sub PintarFinDeSemana()
   ' PintarFinDeSemana Macro

    Dim formato As FormatCondition

    For Each celda In Range("$C$17:$P$71")
        If celda.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then    
            Set formato = celda.FormatConditions(1)
            Debug.Print "Celda a evaluar: " & celda.Address & vbCr

            If Application.Evaluate(formato.Formula1) Then
                Debug.Print "Condición activa"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Sin condición"
            End If
        End If
    Next celda
End Sub
```

Aparentemente está igual que los ejemplos vistos, pero lo dicho, no funciona.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da error? Además, si tienes formato condicional, creo que los colores de formato condicional no son detectables con VBA.

Comment: El error lo da el If por la condicion Application.Evaluate

Comment: A mí no me da error, poniendo una regla de formato condicional simple. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de tus datos, y de la regla de formato condicional que estás intentando acceder? Asegúrate también que sea la primera.